# GCP projects limit and immediate deletion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google

I have two related questions re. GCP and limit on a number of projects:

A) Is there a hard limit on the number of projects allowed per organization? I know the default limit can be increased, just curious if there's any ceiling. Two reasons:

- We're bringing projects under automation, therefore we need to test this and create/delete projects more often.
- We're considering using project per customer model, and I'm wondering if this might limit us in the future.

B) Is there a way to force delete projects immediately? Normally these get shut down and scheduled for deletion in 30-days or so, but even projects that are shut down, do count against the project quota and will prevent you from creating new ones.

Thanks

Comment: Actually, do deleted projects count against the limit?

I'm experiencing some strange behavior - I was unable to create a new project, even after deleting one, but after some time (24h or so) I was able to create a new project without actually changing anything in the meantime. It seems like there's a time-window when deleted projects do count against the limit, and after which they don't? I would like to understand the specifics of this behavior.

Comment: These are good questions for devs new to GCP and wanting to automate project creation / deletion. Not sure why the question is downvoted!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A) There's no hard ceiling for projects' quota, but any quota increase has to be requested on [1]. Regularly, you may get from 5-10 projects to 50 or more, but if you need even more, then it will depend upon your usage of the service and other considerations to grant your organization an higher quota. There's a FAQ that would help you have a better idea about this [2].

B) Currently, immediate deletion of projects is not supported, but you may check and vote a related feature request on [3]. According to the documentation [4], the project will count towards your quota usage until actual deletion of the project.

But, your quota may be automatically adjusted over time. If you deleted the project and tried to create new project and got quota limit error, but then you were able to create a new project, you may check if you can create another one, if you do then your quota may has been automatically increased. In some cases, you can check your remaining quota when creating a project [5].

---

[1] https://support.google.com/code/contact/project_quota_increase

[2] https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6330231

[3] https://googlecloudplatform.uservoice.com/forums/299943--google-cloud-platform/suggestions/32242681-allow-immediate-deletion-of-projects

[4] https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects

[5] https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#managing_project_quotas

Comment: Is there any advice on how to deal with this if we want to test project creation and deletion as part of our CI? It's kind of important part of our automation code, so we would like to run e2e test against real GCP cloud, but as the CI gets triggered for each PR/merge to master, this would leads to possibly many short-lived projects and hitting the limit.

Comment: Assuming that you have already checked tools as Cloud Build and other Continuous Delivery Tool Integrations (which you can find at: cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/continuous-delivery ) and still need to create and delete projects continuously, I remember that Qwiklabs does exactly that for their catalog of GCP Trainings. There would be a whitelist for some organizations to do something similar to Qwiklabs, but you would have to check with GCP through the [contact form](https://support.google.com/code/contact/project_quota_increase)

Comment: Thanks Neri, I've tried to ask Google's support directly, and while increasing quota was possible, we've been told there's no way to delete projects immediately at this time.

Comment: I find this project limit to be a terrible constraint on the usage of GCP.  
It makes me want to consider AWS or even Azure.